# JSON node add attribute

Tags: json, d3.js

I have a JSON file something like below:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    }, ....
```

As you can see, there is a "size" attribute at the end nodes.

I want to add the "size" attribute to other nodes as well (i.e. to "analytics", and "cluster") so what I did was:

```
  {
     "name": "flare",
     "children": [
      {
       {"name": "analytics", "another_size":345},
       "children": [
        {
         {"name": "cluster", "another_size":345},
         "children": [
          {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
          {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
          {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
          {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
         ]
        }, ....
```

But it doesn't compile this way.

How do I go about achieving this? I want to colour my nodes differently for those other nodes under "another_size".

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
      {
         "name": "flare",
         "children": [
          {
           {"name": "analytics", 
            "another_size":345,
           "children": [
            {
             {"name": "cluster", 
              "another_size":345,
             "children": [
              {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
              {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
              {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
              {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
             ]
            }, ....
```

**FULL EXAMPLE**

```
{
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "analytics",
            "another_size": 345,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "cluster",
                    "another_size": 345,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                            "size": 3938
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "CommunityStructure",
                            "size": 3812
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
                            "size": 6714
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "MergeEdge",
                            "size": 743
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "cluster",
                    "another_size": 345,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                            "size": 3938
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "CommunityStructure",
                            "size": 3812
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
                            "size": 6714
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "MergeEdge",
                            "size": 743
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried but it still doesnt work. Where would the "}" end?

Comment: thansk i just saw your full example!